# Cancel a context.Context more than once?

Tags: go, goroutine, cancellation, tui

I'm working on a console music player in `Go`. Whenever the user selects and plays an album, I **launch a goroutine** to **loop** over a playlist.

```
playlist := make([]*Media, 0)
for _, path := range album.Paths {
    media, err := NewMediaFromPath(path)
    // return err

    playlist = append(playlist, media)
}

for idx := range playlist {
    player.SetMedia(playlist[idx])
    err = player.Play()
    // check err

    status, err := player.MediaState()
    // check err

    for status != MediaEnded && status != MediaStopped {
        // update UI and check player status
        // loop until the song finishes
        status, err = player.MediaState()
    }
}
```

I need a way of **canceling** this goroutine when the user **selects a new album**. I'm using `context.Context` to do so (but I'm not convinced it's the best solution).

I create the `ctx`

```
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
```

So in the UI event handler, the `play()` `func` will `cancel()` the goroutine.

This works once I check inside the update UI `for` loop:

```
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return err
        default:
            time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
        }
```

Then the channel `ctx.Done()` is closed and the next albums played will always return instead of loop.

Is there a way to recancel a `context.Context`?

If not, is there a better way to cancel this goroutine (and the following goroutines)?

Alternatively I've tried to use waitgroups,

```
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        wg.Add(1)
        err = playAlbum(
            done,
            player,
            *albums[s],
            list,
            status,
        )
        wg.Done()
        // handle err
     }()
```

But then I get a `sync: WaitGroup is reused before previous Wait has returned` panic

Answer (score 2):

What about using a channel to cancel the goroutine?

```
select {
case <-chClose:
    return
default:
}
```

Your cancel() call could simply close the channel:

```
close(chClose)
```

but then you cannot close it again! So you need to make sure your new album has a new chClose. Depending on your code structure this might be the cleaner solution.

Alternatively you can just send a value on chClose to initiate a stop of the go routine:

```
chClose <- 1
```

You can do that as often as you want.

Note that if there is no goroutine listening, this will block (or if you have a buffer, you will end up closing routines that have not even startet yet. --> You need a clean architecture!!)